# OpenCV: Subdiv2D initializing with a extra vertices

Tags: c++, opencv

For some reason when I'm using Subdiv2D I'm getting an extra vertex (and there no way to remove it)

[the code is embedded in a larger application]

```
Subdiv2D mesh(Rect(0,0,1,1));
vector<Vec6f> triangleList;
mesh.getTriangleList(triangleList);
for(auto triangle : triangleList)
{
        cout <<
            "Vertex 1:" << endl << "\t"
                "x: " << triangle[0] <<
                "y: " << triangle[1] << endl <<
            "Vertex 2:" << endl << "\t"
                "x: " << triangle[2] <<
                "y: " << triangle[3] << endl <<
            "Vertex 3:" << endl << "\t"
                "x: " << triangle[4] <<
                "y: " << triangle[5] << endl <<
            endl;
}
```

On output I get these 2 triangles

```
Vertex 1:
    x: 3y: 0
Vertex 2:
    x: 0y: 3
Vertex 3:
    x: -3y: -3

Vertex 1:
    x: 0y: 3
Vertex 2:
    x: 3y: 0
Vertex 3:
    x: -3y: -3
```

First of all.. the list doesn't make sense (those two triangles are equivalent)
And if I add more vertices, those initial out-of-range vertices remain and muck everything up.

I feel like I must be missing something simple